# How can I have bold for particular cell in excel using java

Tags: java, jxl

May I know how can I use bold in the same code?I need only one row should be in bold. how can I write code for it?

My code,

```
WritableFont cellFont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES,14);
cellFont.setBoldStyle(WritableFont.BOLD); 
WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
cellFormat.setWrap(true); 
Label Sheet1cellContent = new Label(0,0,"LAST NAME",cellFormat);
```

Comment: Post your tried code.

Comment: What have u tried. Post code

Comment: Can you pls add a template excel [in table format]for ur requirement? It will easy to give feedback.

Comment: Are you using Apache POI?

Comment: WritableFont cellFont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES,14);
     cellFont.setBoldStyle(WritableFont.BOLD);
      WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
      cellFormat.setWrap(true);
           
      Label Sheet1cellContent = new Label(0,0,"LAST NAME",cellFormat); while using this code I got full excel in bold.But I need only the first row in bold

Comment: No im not using Apace POI.I am using Jxl

Comment: Last Name First Name DOB Gender

Comment: I added my code already Abhishek singh

Comment: Take look http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html read that fully and then try yourself

Comment: @ArunKumar refer the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848241/different-colors-for-cells-in-excel-sheet-using-jxl

Answer (score 2):

Refer [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/)

```
HSSFFont boldFont = wb.createFont();
boldFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short)22);
boldFont.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD); //Setting Bold font

HSSFCellStyle boldStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
boldStyle.setFont(boldFont); //Attaching the font to the Style

HSSFRow row = sheet1.createRow((short)1);
HSSFCell cell = row.createCell((short)0);
cell.setCellValue("This quick brown fox");
cell.setCellStyle(boldStyle); //Applying Style to the Cell.
```

Comment: can u tell me in Jxl.I am not using Apache POI

Comment: @Arun Kumar post the code you have tried along with your question, so that it will be easy for users to answer

Comment: WritableFont cellFont = new WritableFont(WritableFont.TIMES,14);
     cellFont.setBoldStyle(WritableFont.BOLD);
      WritableCellFormat cellFormat = new WritableCellFormat(cellFont);
      cellFormat.setWrap(true);
      Label Sheet1cellContent = new Label(0,0,"LAST NAME",cellFormat); This is my code.The output of this code is fully bold.I need the first row alone in bold.Can u help me in this?

Comment: Next time, update your tried code in your question not in comment.